# How copy to clipboard with one click (using only JS and jQuery).?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

How copy to clipboard with one click (using only JS, jQuery and AngularJS)? I won't use zclip and flash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: Basic answer, that's not possible